# Parceler performance with transitive entities

Tags: attributes, nested, transitive-dependency, parceler

I'm using [parceler](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler), and I'm trying to define a structure like this one:

```
Category 1..* Product 1..* Images
```

Each entity has a list, and a parent instance, like this

```
@Parcel
public class Category {
    List<Product> products;
    ...
}

@Parcel
public class Product {
    List<Image> images;
    Category parent;
    ...
}

@Parcel
public class Image {
    Product parent;
    ...
}
```

I want to know how performance is affected when I do:

```
Category c = getSampleCategory(); // With products and images
Parcels.wrap(c);
```

and pass a Category object as an extra between activities. 
I'm noticing ANRs and I ask myself if this is one of the causes

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Parceler uses annotation processing and, in turn, generated code to marshal your data to and from the `Bundle` / `Intent` / `Parcel`.  This means that the `Parcels.wrap` / `Parcels.unwrap` calls should be very performant.  I'd encourage you to run your own performance benchmark (surround you calls with timer logging) around the various parts of your code, including the `wrap` / `unwrap` calls to ensure that things are taking a reasonable amount of time.  If you do find that Parceler is not meeting expectations (is a source of your ANRs) please file an issue on the Parceler [issue list on Github](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler/issues).